# Validate that IPN call is from PayPal?

Tags: php, security, paypal, paypal-ipn

How can I validate that a PayPal IPN POST request to my specified notifyURL is indeed coming from PayPal?

I don't mean comparing the data to what I sent earlier, but how can I verify that the server / IP address this PayPal request is coming from is indeed a valid one?

Comment: The methods listed here for validating where the IPN post back came from aren't foolproof, and don't really make you much more secure than you already are.  Implement the best practices as recommended by PayPal.  If they were insecure, PayPal would have bigger issues, considering their entire brand is built on users' trust.

Answer (score 16):

> The IPN protocol consists of three
>   steps:
>
> 1. PayPal sends your IPN listener a
>      message that notifies you of the event
> 2. Your listener sends the complete
>      unaltered message back to PayPal; the
>      message must contain the same fields
>      in the same order and be encoded in
>      the same way as the original message
> 3. PayPal sends a single word back, which
>      is either VERIFIED if the message
>      originated with PayPal or INVALID if
>      there is any discrepancy with what was
>      originally sent

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro

Comment: thanks, i'm aware of that and i'm doing that exactly... but how can I be doubly sure that its PayPal that calls my IPN listener? (the step 1 that you've copy-pasted)?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to be? After all, the entire point of the 3-step process outlined above is that it's impossible for someone else to call your IPN listener and still get a VERIFIED response...

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with man-in-the-middle type attacks, but I'm thinking a stronger verification that the request is coming from PayPal would be more prudent...

Comment: More or less on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856530/paypal-ipn-security

Comment: matt74tm: There is nothing "stronger", as long as your code is actually hard-coded to send the request to *paypal*, and not simply whatever host sent you the original request. You have two options for specifying where to send it: domain name or IP. The former could (theoretically) be compromised by someone taking over your DNS server, though that's unlikely. The latter couldn't be compromised via DNS, but could simply break if PayPal ever changed their IP.

Comment: Yes there is a good reason for this, when using multiple payment methods I would like to know which call is being made by who to then verify.

Comment: @siliconpi I agree. It's idiotic they way they have it. The IPN should be delivered over HTTPS with a client certificate.

Comment: This is not correct: you send back the exact same message to PayPal, EXCEPT with "&cmd=_notify-validate" added to the end.

Answer (score 12):

This is the easiest way I have found to do it, also as per PayPal suggests. I uses http_build_query() to construct the url from the post that was sent to the site from paypal. Paypal docs states that you should send this back for verification and that is what we do with file_get_contents. you will note that I use strstr to check if the word 'VERIFIED' is present and so we continue in the function, if not we return false...

```
$verify_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&' . http_build_query( $_POST );   

if( !strstr( file_get_contents( $verify_url ), 'VERIFIED' ) ) return false;
```

Comment: Actually, paypal says you should POST the body back to them: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: HTTP header User-Agent required now!

Answer (score 3):

<del>https://gist.github.com/mrded/a596b0d005e84bc27bad</del>

```
function paypal_is_transaction_valid($data) {
  $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
  ));
  $content = file_get_contents('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate', false, $context);

  return (bool) strstr($content, 'VERIFIED');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTTP header User-Agent required now!**

```
$vrf = file_get_contents('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate', false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nUser-Agent: MyAPP 1.0\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($_POST)
    )
)));

if ( $vrf == 'VERIFIED' ) {
    // Check that the payment_status is Completed
    // Check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // Check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // Check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment
}
```

Comment: If I'm testing with the sandbox, would the URL be www.sandbox.paypal.com to authenticate with, or www.paypal.com?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the PayPal uses a static IP for it's IPN calls.

So, checking for the correct IP should work.

alternatively, you could make use of [`gethostbyaddr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) or [`gethostbyname`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php).

Comment: +1 for reminding me that it might be static. it's been years since I did any IPN programming.

Answer (score -1):

This is [what I use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856530/paypal-ipn-security):

```
if (preg_match('~^(?:.+[.])?paypal[.]com$~', gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) > 0)
{
    // came from paypal.com (unless your server got r00ted)
}
```

Comment: What if I bought the domain blablablarandomstuffpaypal.com? wouldn't it match this regex? a `[.]` before `paypal` should fix this.

Comment: @aularon: It wouldn't match because of the `^`.

Comment: Can easily be spoofed.  See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/