# Reject transaction after receiving IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Is it possible to reject / auto refund after receiving IPN message with `COMPLETED` status but the `txn_id` is duplicated or the price value is incorrect?

Or manual investigation need to be done to refund

Comment: You can call the refund API. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are [verifying your IPN calls with PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848227/validate-that-ipn-call-is-from-paypal), this should (in theory) be impossible. PayPal never duplicates transaction IDs.

Comment: So why does all their sample IPN code have checkes for duplicates?

Comment: Because you can be sent the same IPN more than once if PayPal doesn't get a 200 response

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to reject / auto refund after receiving IPN message with COMPLETED status but the txn_id is duplicated or the price value is incorrect?

You can't reject the transaction with IPN. You aren't in a transaction. You're getting notification that a transaction has already occurred.

You may be able to use *another* API to reverse the transaction, as suggested by @geewhiz.